# cuncurrency bugs with c# threads and tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

**Description**
I have a sample code to do threaded parallel online logins. It takes the number of logins to attempt in the `Main` and passes it to `ParallelRun`. `ParallelRun` divides the `longinAttemptsCount` by the number of threads. It then spawns the threads and passes a thread id and the number of attempts per thread to `ThreadAuthenticationTaskRunner`

`AuthenticateAsync` does the actual logging in.

`ThreadAuthenticationTaskRunner` prints out what thread is starting, and once done, it prints out what thread has ended.

**Expected Results**

I would expect to see the threads listed in any order but I should not see duplicated Ids.

**Actual results**

I see some thread Ids missing and others are duplicated.
I receive results such as:

[image]

What is this concurrency bug I am seeing here?

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Stylelabs.M.WebSdk.Examples
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int longinAttemptsCount = 1000;
            Console.WriteLine("Main Thread Started");

            //parallel run 
            ParallelRun(longinAttemptsCount);

            Console.WriteLine("Main Thread Ended");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Takes the number of required login attempts and spreads it across threads
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="longinAttemptsCount"> Number of times to attempt to login</param>
        static void ParallelRun(int longinAttemptsCount)
        {
            int numberOfLoginAttemptsPerThread = 100;

            int numberOfThreads = longinAttemptsCount / numberOfLoginAttemptsPerThread;

            Console.WriteLine("ParallelRun Started: " + numberOfThreads + " threads");

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
            {
                Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => ThreadAuthenticationTaskRunner(i, numberOfLoginAttemptsPerThread));
                thread1.Start();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("ParallelRun Ended: " + numberOfThreads + " threads");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Runs parallel logins for each thread
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="threadId">The identifier of the running thread </param>
        /// <param name="longinAttemptsCount">Number of times to attempt to login </param>
        static async void ThreadAuthenticationTaskRunner(int threadId, int longinAttemptsCount)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ThreadAuthenticationTaskRunner start for thread: " + threadId);

            string userName = "administrator"; //user to log in

            List<Task<String>> loginAttemptsResultsTasks = new List<Task<String>>();
            //Executing the parallel logins 
            for (int i = 0; i < longinAttemptsCount; i++)
            {
                loginAttemptsResultsTasks.Add(AuthenticateAsync(userName, i, threadId));
            }

            var loginAttemptsResults = await Task.WhenAll(loginAttemptsResultsTasks);

            foreach (string login in loginAttemptsResults)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(login);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("ThreadAuthenticationTaskRunner end for thread: " + threadId);

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Conducts an asynchronous login on a QA tenant 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userName"> The user to be logged in </param>
        /// <param name="loginId"> The login attempt identifier </param>
        /// <param name="threadId"> The identifier of the running thread </param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        static async Task<String> AuthenticateAsync(String userName, int loginId, int threadId)
        {
            String result;

            try
            {
                //some asynchronous login logic here

                result = "Success: loginId: " + loginId + " threadId: " + threadId;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                result = "Failure: loginId: " + loginId + " threadId: " + threadId + " error: " + e;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you run into the problem that the `int i` is not passed by reference, not by value. Try copying the value to a tmp variable inside the loop: `for (int i = 0; ....) { var copy = i; ..Runner(copy, ...)`

Comment: @stefan hmmm :) that is indeed true. Is this a C# issue or a general concurrency issue?
And thank you!

Comment: its a detail of the closure you are creating () => ThreadAuthenticationTaskRunner(i, numberOfLoginAttemptsPerThread) - not sure if its specific to c# or its just a general thing with the standard implementation of closures. Wouldn't consider it an issue, just a implementation detail you need to be aware of

Comment: might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp

Comment: On a side note, prefer `Task.Run` over `Thread`. Using `async void` with `Thread` can cause some surprising behavior.

Comment: @StephenCleary I will look into this further. Just started learning concurrency, I am quite green here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that

```cs
() => ThreadAuthenticationTaskRunner(i, numberOfLoginAttemptsPerThread)
```

captures a reference to the locale variable `i`. Then when the function is invoked it will lock up which value the variable currently has. The problem now araises that `Thread.Start` may return before the lambda was invoked to the loop continues, increases the value for `i` and then the new thead reads a wrong value for its id.

The simple solution as @stefan alreasy mentioned is to introduce a new variable in the loop, like:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
{
    var tmp = i;
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => ThreadAuthenticationTaskRunner(tmp, numberOfLoginAttemptsPerThread));
    thread1.Start();
}
```

that waw the lambda caputers it's own `tmp` variable which no one will change.
Notice that every loop iteration will have theri own `tmp` variable and that they will mostlily live on the heap and not the stack.